# Find a element based on the part of a string and get the value

Tags: python, loops, generator, filepath

I have a filepath created by

```
Path('filepath')
```

I would like to get a directory name in the middle of file path and append this to a list.
And the condition of selection is a specific part of a string.
I've tried

```
list = []
list.append(x for x in str(filepath).split(os.sep) if 'part of a sting' in x)
```

I tried this but when I print out only

```
print(x for x in str(filepath).split(os.sep) if 'part of a sting' in x)
```

it gave me generator format not the part of filepath

```
<generator object function.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f23c8dd0258>
```

what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the generator object because you are using the generator expression instead of the list comprehension. You could read more about generator expressions [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)

try to write something like:

```
path_list = [x for x in str(filepath).split(os.sep) if 'part of a sting' in x]
print(path_list)
```